# Use same VM as self hosted integration runtime for two different adf instances

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My question is very clear. As you can understand from the title, I want to use the same VM as self-hosted integration runtime for two different ADF instances. Is it possible to do that?

I can not see any option to register new ADF instances on Microsoft Integration Runtime Configuration Manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can share same VM as self-hosted IR with different data factories.

Currently self-hosted integration runtime can only be shared with multiple data factories, it can't be shared across Synapse workspaces or between data factory and Synapse workspace.

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell#create-a-shared-self-hosted-ir-using-azure-data-factory-ui) shows how to do it.

[Considerations for using a self-hosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir)

Comment: A limitation is that the SHIR cannot be shared with data factories from different tenants.

Comment: Hi AbhishekKhandave-MT,
Thanks for the answer. 
But there is no information on how I can add a new ADF instance through the Microsoft Integration Runtime Manager.

Comment: @AnupamChand  I just wanted to have static IP for my linked service (integration runtime), Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: You can refer to the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell. As long as both your ADFs are on the same tenant you can use 1 SHIR and share it between the 2 ADFs.